# PHP Loop Object member manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, yii2

I have a multi dimensional object result set to which I want to loop through to change a value of an inner object member to the value of an outer object member. When the loop finishes executing, even though the values of each outer object member is different, the values of the inner object member are all the same value which is the value of the final outer object member.

```
foreach ($user as $key => &$value) {
    $user[$key]->user->company = $value->Company;
}
```

When I dump the $user array which contains the objects I get This as my result:

```
Array
(
[0] => common\models\UserRoleMapping Object
(
    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [User_Role_Mapping_Id] => 9b55d3a7-8de6-11e5-ae99-60a44ce86902
        [User_Id] => 9b432c2c-8de6-11e5-ae99-60a44ce86902
        [User_Role_Id] => 49c82d92-31d0-11e4-8309-60a44ce86902                    
        [Status] => 8332b8d7-1990-11e4-8876-60a44ce86902
        [Company] => 79538f95-7e25-11e5-b514-60a44ce86902                    
    )

    [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [user] => common\models\User Object
        (                            
            [company] => 0e7505fc-7961-11e5-a563-60a44ce86902
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [User_Id] => 9b432c2c-8de6-11e5-ae99-60a44ce86902
                [Username] => andre@hotmail.com
                [Password] => fbb8f9f42cb0532f30759d9e4fa3e2fc90d714321ce11fdc42f5c9b23756979c6166e674e421b8580ab53a0e75e9d2758f7b8bbe70a33a5ad0cdc25b553e08b4
                [Login_Status] => Offline
                [Failed_Login_Attempts] => 0
                [Verification] => 
                [Salt] => dd7c8a297a8d34ba5dc7cd4b45a1e593
                [Last_Reset] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [Status] => 8332b8d7-1990-11e4-8876-60a44ce86902
            )
        )
    )
)
[1] => common\models\UserRoleMapping Object
(
    [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [User_Role_Mapping_Id] => fdb962ef-8de6-11e5-ae99-60a44ce86902
        [User_Id] => 9b432c2c-8de6-11e5-ae99-60a44ce86902
        [User_Role_Id] => 49c82d92-31d0-11e4-8309-60a44ce86902                    
        [Status] => 8332b8d7-1990-11e4-8876-60a44ce86902
        [Company] => 0e7505fc-7961-11e5-a563-60a44ce86902                    
    )
    [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [user] => common\models\User Object
        (                            
            [company] => 0e7505fc-7961-11e5-a563-60a44ce86902
            [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
            (
                [User_Id] => 9b432c2c-8de6-11e5-ae99-60a44ce86902
                [Username] => andre@hotmail.com
                [Password] => fbb8f9f42cb0532f30759d9e4fa3e2fc90d714321ce11fdc42f5c9b23756979c6166e674e421b8580ab53a0e75e9d2758f7b8bbe70a33a5ad0cdc25b553e08b4
                [Login_Status] => Offline
                [Failed_Login_Attempts] => 0
                [Verification] => 
                [Salt] => dd7c8a297a8d34ba5dc7cd4b45a1e593
                [Last_Reset] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                [Status] => 8332b8d7-1990-11e4-8876-60a44ce86902
            )
        )
    )
)
)
```

As you can see in the dumped values, both inner user objects have the same value for their company member which the value Found in the final Outer Object Company member.

I am seeking assistance with how I can get each inner user object to have their respective outer object company values.

Comment: both `_attributes` and `_related` properties are private, you need to use the specific getter and setter methods to access the "inner" data

Comment: You are simply modifying the same user object : the company attribute will be the last Company value in the loop... I don't see the meaning of all this, you should add details about what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: @soju Ok what I am trying to achieve is setting the value found for the UserRoleMapping object Company member to the User Object company member within the foreach loop. When the loop completes, it sets all user Object company members to the value found in the final   UserRoleMapping Object Company member, I do not understand why this occurs even though I iterate the $value by reference. Both UserRoleMapping have a different value for their Company member so i want both user Object company members to have the values set based on their respective UserRoleMapping Object

Comment: @AlexAndrei I have mutators within the class, I just removed them from within the foreach loop but the company member for the user class is a public member not protect and not private.

Comment: @mezlad : read carefully my previous comment, your UserRoleMapping objects have all the same user object...

Comment: @soju Thanks. I thought because even though they have the same user values (I did that intentionally) coming from the database, I thought each UserRoleMapping would have referenced different portions of memory. I kind a found a work around to for it. I was using the result sets in 2 different scenarios within the application I am developing. One scenario is looping through each result in a regular view, the other is sending it via JSON through VIA an API endpoint.

Comment: @soju Theoretically what I was trying to achieve is that two companies can have the same user row but the person details for each user can vary based on the company which has the user attached to it. So in doing the loop I was just simply trying to get the person details for the user based on the company the UserRoleMapping object Company member value was saved as.